# OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x66a4cc30 successful, but not so successful

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I've been spending the day trying to find from where this message comes from:

```
[OMXNodeInstance] OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x66a4cc30 successful
```

I'm running a `MediaCodec` decoder that feeds a `MediaCodec` encoder, and after just one run, it starts to crash with this message appearing about 20 times, then the application crashes.

What is OMX, and what can be the origin of this warning and crash?

[Update]

This crashes comes with the disparition of all exception handling when running the code. I've found the crash (a null array), but it's just not handled, nor showing any crash output in the IDE.

Comment: OMX is short for [OpenMAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMAX).

Comment: So OpenMax is crashing in my application.

Comment: That can't be concluded from the information you've provided.

Comment: I've debugged line-by-line, and when debugging slowly, there is no bug, so I can't find the culprit anywhere. If I just launch the app, I think it can crash anywhere where MediaCodec and buffers are used. I'm thinking about adding Log.d(..) after each line.

Comment: OMX defines the API that the OEMs provide for their A/V hardware. Saying "OpenMAX is crashing in my application" is like saying "OpenGL is crashing in my application" when you're drawing graphics. (They're both from Khronos, BTW.) The error message you're seeing doesn't necessarily relate to the crash. You need to show the crash in your question. From what you've posted we can't even tell if it's a Java-language exception or a native crash.

Comment: I think, but it's a big supposition, that something in OpenMax or in what is used by MediaCodec is hijacking the normal debugger error handler when debugging, because I noticed that in certain place in my application, I just can't catch exceptions, and instead of receiving a memory error, or a null error (i.e. for a null element of an array), I see OpenMax that panics with all these OMX_FreeBuffer, when this is actually just a very basic crash that is just not handled in the code.